# ReferenceError: document is not defined in vsCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm trying to debug my javascript code and I've tried everything, I even uninstalled vscode, but I can never debug, does anyone know how to fix it? The following message is appearing: (remembering that I'm learning to program so if you can explain it in a very basic way, I'd appreciate it)

I expected to be able to debug my code, I tried to uninstall vscode and reinstall, update and nothing, I searched for several days for what it could be... But the following error only happens:
[image]

Comment: You are trying to debug code written for the browser by executing it in node.js. That doesn't work. Put the script in a html page, open that in a browser, and debug your code there. VsCode may be able to connect to the browser devtools for a more integrated debugging experience, see the documentation for how to set that up.

Comment: Thanks, it worked and I finally managed to fix my code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`document` is not defined in node.js. It is available only in browser. So, if you are trying to write code that should run on browser, you should test it with browser debugging tools (Can be integrated with VS code).